# Quadratics substitute problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ok, so I can make the substitution $z^4=u^2$ to solve $az^4+bz^2+c=0,\:\forall\:a,b,c\in\mathbb{R},\:a\neq0$?

Comment: Yes, you can, together with $z^2=u$.

Comment: ok, but then $z^2=|u|$ and I am losing solutions that way!

Comment: @Numbers have a look at my answer. The two instances of $\pm$ indicate there are four solutions, as expected of a fourth degree polynomial. Also you're losing values because instead of taking $z^2=|u|$ you should take $z^2=\pm u$

Comment: Yeah, u r right, thx man!

Answer (score 1):

This is what is known as a biquadratic. Notice we can rewrite it as:

$$a(z^2)^2+b(z^2)^1+c(z^2)^0=0$$ and we have a quadratic. So we use the quadratic equation for:
$$z^2=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\to z=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}$$

In other words, yes, what you are saying is correct.